# what is the easiest way to implement Elasticsearch search query in java?

Tags: elasticsearch

what is the easiest way to implement Elasticsearch  search query in java.Like can we write the exact query in java in the form of string without using any predefined class.

Comment: Your Java code can construct a search query in JSON format, but that's error prone. Why don't you want to use the Java classes from Elasticsearch which will do that for you?

Comment: Because I have a big nested query which is difficult to write in predefined java class.Moreovere ,there are no step by step tutorial that can help me to convert my json query to java class. If anyone has any documentation let me know